# Is it possible to remove a word from a NHunspell object

Tags: nhunspell

You can add words to NHunspell (.NET port of Hunspell) as such

```
NHunspell.Hunspell hunspell = new NHunspell.Hunspell(".affPath", ".dicPath");
String[] words = GetUserWords();
foreach (String word in words)
  hunspell.Add(word);
```

What if I need to remove a word from the object?  Is there a way to remove a word from the NHunspell object without having to create a new one and adding custom words again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (1.1.0.0) remove is not implemented in NHunspell but i consider to implement it in the next version

Addition:
Since ( 1.1.1.0) remove is implemented.

Comment: Thank you.  I look forward to the next version!